# CSS extra spacing when flex-wrap contents over body height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I have flex-wrap div and several items inside. But when screen get smaller, body height can't follow their height and make space at bottom. Why it happens and how to solve it?

[image: explain flexwrap over body height]
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ko" class="bg-orange">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div class="project">
        <div class="prototype-box">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
```

style.css

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.project {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.prototype-box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: you set a `px` height to the boxes try to give them something like this:`height :32vh`

Comment: @לבנימלכה I don't want to change content's height. Just want to make body height follow content's total height.

Comment: but the total contant's height is longer then the body... You have to fit it to body with `%`  or `vh`

Comment: see here:https://jsfiddle.net/o127wyg9/

Comment: @SooJungChae if you remove `height: 100%` `body` will follow the height of the `project` div... you want to *shrink* the `prototype-box`es within the viewport?

Answer (score 2):

try not to touch the body and insert your flex div inside a wrapper div. so you can make the spacing. you can refer to my pen here.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
wrapper{ /* Add this wrapper */
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 10% 0;
}
.project {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    /* add the code below */
    background-color: red;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.prototype-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  /* Add this code */
  width: auto;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper"> <!-- Add this wrapper -->
    <div class="project">
        <div class="prototype-box">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `px` to `height` what means it absolute. So for example, 200px will be literally 200 pixels on any screen.
So if the body height is smaller then `600px` (`200px+200px+200px`) scroll(`overflow-y`) will show by default...

If you want them to fit `body's height` you have to set `%/vh` to `height`

**Percentage** (%): Relative to the parent value.

**Viewport height** (vh): Size relative to the viewport (browser window, basically).

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}

.project {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.prototype-box {
border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 32vh;
}
```

```html
   <div class="project">
        <div class="prototype-box">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="prototype-box">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you made the `body` limited to height:100% of the `html` which limited to height:100% of the screen. To fix this simply use `min-height` instead of `height` within the body:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.prototype-box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <div class="prototype-box">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="prototype-box">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="prototype-box">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```